# Misspecified regression & asymptotics

Tags: regression, asymptotics, weighted-regression, misspecification

Consider the weighted regression coefficient

$\hat{\beta} = (X'WX)^{-1}X'WY$

where the regression is possibly misspecified and $W$ is known.

Let

$\beta_* = (E[X'WX])^{-1}E[X'WY]$

and the related error $\epsilon_* = Y - X\beta_*$

Under which conditions do we have

$X'W\epsilon_*/n = Op(n^{-1/2})$

In particular, how do I prove that

$X'W\epsilon_*/n \to_p 0$?

Note that we the regression model may be misspecified.

Comment: If $W$ is nonrandom (since you said it is known), you in general need $E(X_{i} \varepsilon_{i*}) = 0$. Then the statement follows from the LLN.

Comment: "Misspecification" covers many different cases. Which misspecification do you have in mind?

Comment: That $E[Y | X]$ cannot be written as $X \beta$